# Python integer list.append() operation issue

Tags: python, list, loops, integer, local-variables

I think I am having some issues with understanding why my integers that I append to a list only stay within the loop, but outside of it the list is empty.

For this exercise I am trying to create a program that takes a number and uses a ***recursive*** function to output the syracuse sequence.

```
import sys

def syracuse(nr):
    ''' syracuse function '''

    nr = int(nr)
    seq = []
    if nr != 1:
        if (nr % 2 != 0):
            n =  3*nr+1
        else:
            n = nr // 2
        seq.append(n)
        print(seq)
        syracuse(n)
    else:
        return seq

def main(argv):
    ''' main function '''
    if len(argv) == 2:
        print(syracuse(argv[1]))

    else:
        print("Error! One number should be included in the query."
        .format(argv[0]), file = sys.stderr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

With input '5' my output is:

```
[16]
[8]
[4]
[2]
[1]
None
```

So my question is: How come my list 'seq' outputs 'None', when the variable 'n' does get appended to it in my if nr!=1 loop. How can you extract variables out of loops? Is this the thing that I do not understand or is there something else?

I hope my question is coherent. Thanks in advance.

Please note that although I know Python does not work well for ***recursive*** functions, this is the exercise and I have to implement it.

Comment: You are not handling `seq` down to the next level in recursion. So, every recursion steps creates a new own version of `seq`.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call the function, you are resetting the list. 
To prevent that, use the list as an argument:

```
def syracuse(nr, seq=[]):
nr = int(nr)
if nr != 1:
    if (nr % 2 != 0):
        n =  3*nr+1
    else:
        n = nr // 2
    seq.append(n)
    print(seq)
    syracuse(n, seq)
else:
    return seq
```